# Sequence of independent RV

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of independent RVs that converges in probability to some RV $X$. Show that $X$ is constant a.e.

**My attempt**

So from definition of convergence I have:

$$\forall\epsilon>0 \:\:\:\mathbb{P}(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)\longrightarrow0$$

I think that there is some useful theorem that I don't know. Can anyone help? I mean just give me some tip, not necessarily full answer.